# Regex to capture variable names in an expression?

Tags: regex

I need a little parser in my javascript application to capture user input and execute it.

Expressions will be simple variable names, numbers or arithmetic operators to capture expressions like "(weeks*2) +(3*days)"

I plan on converting all the variables names in the string to numbers first and then using a window function to evaluate the numeric expression.

In order to do that I need to pull out all the variables names and replace them with numbers.

Tryinig to write a regex which extracts the variable names I came up with:

```
 (?:\s\/+\-\*\()?([A-Za-z_]+[A-Za-z_0-9]*)(?:\s\+\-\/\*\))?
```

which looks for variable names strings surrounded by arithmetic operators, parens or spaces, but avoid capturing any function invocations.

However when I run this test string in regextester.com

```
  a+3+cats+dogs(32)*(cats+dogs)+ x[horse_3]
```

I get this result:

[image: this result]

which is progress, but I don't understand why 'dogs' in `dogs(32)` is being captured, since 'dogs' isn't  followed by an operator, space or close paren, and why `horse_3` and `x` are captured since they don't fit either? (bracket not specified as a permitted char to follow or precede..]

How can I fix this regex so it only captures names that are preceded by nothing (start of string), an operator a space or open paren, and followed by a the same list except only close paren not open paren?

Comment: You probably want to put `\s\/+\-\*\(` in character class, and since these are optional, there doesn't need to be a preceding or following character for the tokens to match

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your regex. Firstly, your non-capturing groups are looking for this sequence of characters:

```
<space>/+-*(
```

(`)` instead of `(` in the ending group) where you should be using a character class to match only one of those:

```
[\s/+*(-]
```

Secondly, you make all the delimiter characters optional (the `?` after the non-capturing groups) so they don't actually restrict the match at all. That is why you are matching `dogs` in `dogs(32)` and `x[horse_3]`.

Finally, because you use non-capturing groups, you won't be able to capture consecutive variables e.g. `cats+dogs` because the match on `cats` will absorb the `+` prior to `dogs`, preventing a match.

I think this regex should do what you want. It uses the appropriate character classes, and it uses a positive lookahead in place of the second non-capturing group. To allow for matching at the beginning and end of line, `^` and `$` are added as alternations in the non-capturing group and the lookahead:

```
(?:^|[\s/+*(-])([A-Za-z_]+[A-Za-z_0-9]*)(?=[\s+/*)-]|$)
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uSJW5k/1)

In JS

```js
let str = 'a+3+cats+dogs(32)*(cats+dogs)+ x[horse_3]+z';
let r = /(?:^|[\s/+*(-])([A-Za-z_]+[A-Za-z_0-9]*)(?=[\s+/*)-]|$)/g;
while (m = r.exec(str)) {
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried something like that, and I just copied this string over to regex tester, but it appears to be capturing the plus sign in "+cats" and "+dogs" and the open parent in "(cats"   I was having this problem of not being able to exclude the operators.  Is this some kind of flaw with regextester.com?

Comment: @user1023110 the match as a whole will always include the non-capturing groups as well. You need to look at group 1, which will contain the variable name. If you look at my regex101 demo, group 1 is where the names are, and the JS code also accesses only group 1 in the match. If you had a version of JS that supported lookbehinds you could avoid that issue but most versions don't.

Comment: Ah.  I thought that was not "non-capturing" meant.  So no way for the regex to only capture the var names without preceding operator in most modern browser's javascript?

Comment: Some browsers do support lookbehinds but Firefox and Safari don't as yet, IE doesn't and only the most recent version of Edge does  (see https://caniuse.com/#feat=js-regexp-lookbehind).